# Position: fixed on CSS media print seems to duplicate content on print?

Tags: css, printing, position, duplicates, fixed

Given the div:

```
    ...
    <div id='section-to-print'>CONT
        /*Content*/
    </div>
    ...
```

And the CSS

```
    @media print {
    * {
        -webkit-transition: none !important;
        transition: none !important;
      }
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      #section-to-print {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }  
      #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
        visibility: visible;
      } 
    }
```

Whenever I print (e.g. ctrl+ p)it shows only whatever is in the /*content*/ region (as expected). However the content is duplicated. If I emulate the print media in chrome it shows correctly. Also, I noticed if I remove/change the `position: fixed;` in the CSS makes it work "properly" (not duplicating), but at the wrong position.

I couldn't find any similar problems on google and honestly I never ever saw this behavior before.

Does anybody know why is it duplicating the content when I try to print?
Also, I tried on more than 1 computer, same behavior on all.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution having the same problem. Please, try to use position static instead of fixed! Wierd right?

A few more information about the problem:
http://css-101.org/fixed-positioning/index.php

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a consistent solution to keep text in a specific position such as a page footer. Good question though - currently dealing with it and having issues finding solutions.